# Appear an Android Studio error, when I try to run app

Tags: android

What should I do for this error?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>           at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-3cb7714597efe9e3659aaddc0b1ef95503d57541.jar (A rendszer nem találja a megadott elérési utat)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:220)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:150)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:164)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-6cd09a3c266a30acff979393d91898af1c440c1a.jar (A rendszer nem találja a megadott elérési utat)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:220)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:150)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:164)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-b97aa2ff66c24cee2da72ca7d96dd6cb2ab9e4ec.jar (A rendszer nem találja a megadott elérési utat)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:220)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:150)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:164)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Camera_test_01\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-f797dc3665367ba378ae209f0bab0d07436ece43.jar (A rendszer nem találja a megadott elérési utat)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:220)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:150)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:164)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       5 errors; aborting

This problem appear, when I try to Run my app.

Answer (score 0):

What's in you dependencies?
Check your **build.grade**.
Maybe you are importing appcompact v7 and v4 support classes at the same time.